# enable pdo_sqlsrv in php 7.2, not working

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp, sqlsrv

I have followed all the guided path,

1. download the appropriate sql driver for php 7.2 from https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases
2. copy and past the ts files to my xampp/php/ext folder,
3. enabled the extension from php.ini file
4. Restart the xampp and check php info
   but I couldn't see the extension enabled in phpinfo
   [image]

I need to know, is it the version issue or I missed out something.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to run as an administrator.
2. An ODBC driver is missing.

Comment: ODBC driver is already there, as you can see in the picture, and which thing I need to run as an administrator?

Comment: As administrator ! Run the wampserver

Answer (score 0):

Installation of PHP Driver for SQL Server can be done following the next steps:

- select and download appropriate version of this driver following [Microsoft PHP Drivers for SQL Server Support Matrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-drivers-for-sql-server-support-matrix?view=sql-server-2017).
- download and install an appropriate ODBC driver following [System Requirements for the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017)
- [load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/loading-the-php-sql-driver?view=sql-server-2017) PHP Driver for SQL Server as PHP extension.
- restart Apache

Example:

```
<?php
# Info
$server   = 'server\instance,port';
$database = 'database';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';

# Connect
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server;Database=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die("Error connecting to SQL Server".$e->getMessage());
}

# End
echo 'Connected';
$conn = null;
?>
```